# Debug button in bottom toolbar leads to "launch: program '[program_name]' does not exits." with CMake Tools

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

Since the Extension `CMake Tools` (1.3.1) is maintained directly by Microsoft the helper extension that created the bridge between `ms-vscode.cpptools` and this tool is not compatible anymore and as of that, the `launch.json` is not created automatically anymore.

If I manually create the `launch.json` as follows:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "test",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${command:cmake.buildDirectory}/test",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and define `cmake.buildDirector` in the `settings.json`

```
"cmake.buildDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/build/${command:cmake.buildKit}/${command:cmake.buildType}",
```

the building works fine, and I can launch the application with the correct kit and build type from the `Run` side panel clicking on the run-symbol.

But if I hit the "Debug" button in the bottom toolbar of the VSCode window I get `launch: program '[test]' does not exits`, with the option "Cancel" or "Open launch.json"

Does anyone know what might cause this problem or how this can be debugged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem is.

The `Debug` button uses the `cmake.debugConfig` and there for `program` the value seems to be `${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}`.

For my setup `${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}` referees only the the application name.

If I change the `settings.json` to this:

```
    "cmake.debugConfig": {
            "program": "${command:cmake.buildDirectory}/${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
    },
```

then the debug button works again.